# Undistorted image captured by camera and projected by a dlp projector

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, distortion, projector

I am projecting an image on the wall using a DLP projector and then capturing the scene with a pin-hole camera. Both the camera and projector have a radial distortion.

I calibrated both of them simultaneously until I get the distortion coefficient for both of them.

How should undistorted the captured image in order to cancel the both distortion (which came from camera and projector) in order to get an image that, theoretically, matches exactly the one I send it to the projector at first.

I am using OpenCV but any theoretical hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you calibrated them, then presumably you can just undistort using those coefficients.

Also, if you calibrate the camera separately, then you can then undistort the projected images and use these undistorted images to calibrate the projector.

Comment: Thanks but I have two set of coefficients, one for projector and one for camera. Which one should I use?

Comment: You should probably undistort with the camera params first then undistort the result with the projector params.